# Decide value from django template 'int' or 'str'

Tags: python, django

I have a form in django template. In the view that gets data from this form, I need to check if the entry is 'str' or 'int'. If it's 'str', I have to raise an error. But when I check the type of the entry by using:

```
pr = request.GET['pr no']
print "Type of PR:%s" % type(pr)
```

irrespective of the 'pr' being string or integer, type() function returns 'unicode'. How do I go about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, obviously `.GET['pr no']` always returns a `Unicode` object then.

Whether that string contains an integer can be tested:

```
if pr.isdigit():   # ASCII digits
```

or

```
if pr.isnumeric(): # also Unicode digits
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
try:
    int(pr)
except ValueError:
    print "PR is not an integer"
```

or check for any valid number:

```
try:
    float(pr)
except ValueError:
    print "PR is not a number"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I have change var name to _, excuse the boldness.

Comment: @danihp: no problem, your edit made me realize that no assignment is needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

In html form, text input box is used to input integer values. So values you get in python view for it will always be unicode string.

To achieve what you want to do, you can test with `.isdigit()` method of unicode string.

Example:

```
>>> x=u'99A'
>>> x.isdigit()
False
>>> x=u'99'
>>> x.isdigit()
True
>>> 
>>> x=u'A99'
>>> x.isdigit()
False
>>>
```

If you are using django form, you may want to use appropriate form field (likely [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) ) and validate the form to get errors.